# How to format legend set shadow preset outer whit apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I need to format Excel as shown below with apache poi and java, but I don't know how to format the legend with Apache POI. Can anyone help me with formatting? Thank you, everyone.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPkL5.png)

I've tried, but I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

A [XDDFChartLegend](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartLegend.html) has methods `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTShapeProperties getShapeProperties()` and `void setShapeProperties(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTShapeProperties properties)`. Those `CTShapeProperties` may have fill properties which may be solid fill having a RGB color set.

Example:

```java
...
XDDFChartLegend legend ...
...
org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTShapeProperties shapeProperties = legend.getShapeProperties();
if (shapeProperties == null) shapeProperties = org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTShapeProperties.Factory.newInstance();
if (shapeProperties.getSolidFill() == null) shapeProperties.addNewSolidFill();
if (shapeProperties.getSolidFill().getSrgbClr() == null) shapeProperties.getSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr();
shapeProperties.getSolidFill().getSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{0,(byte)255,0});
System.out.println(shapeProperties);
legend.setShapeProperties(shapeProperties);
...
```